# jQuery: How to update input field value (not working in Chrome)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, input

Currently, I have a number of input fields sharing the same class `inputField`, and I have a `.blur` event which trims any strings entered on focus-out and updates the field with the result, like so:

```
$('.inputField').blur(function() {
   var input = $.trim($(this).val());
   $(this).val(input);
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class='form'>
   <label>Email Address:</label>
   <input id='input_emailAddress' class='inputField' type='email' name='input_emailAddress'>
   <label>Confirm Email:</label>
   <input id='input_emailAddressConf' class='inputField' type='email' name='input_emailAddressConf'>
</div>
```

Works great in Firefox, Safari, but not in Chrome (not sure about IE). I tried removing/re-adding the class to force a "refresh" but no go. Is it a known issue? Curious what a good/clean solution would be?  Thanks!

Edit P.S. Again, the code itself works fine. It's not a syntax problem -- JSHint is all clear, no errors in console. It only doesn't work in Chrome (ver 30.0+) Thanks!

Comment: It's working fine for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/qb8Sq/ - does your code have a missing `);` at the end like your question?

Comment: @ Joe: Yes, works for me in your jsFiddle. However, I had proper closing of the block in my code, so this isn't the issue.

Comment: Ok, would you be able to post your html as well?

Comment: To whomever down-voted my question as "shows no effort": I spent an hour+ on this issue; I may not be as knowledgeable as you but I don't think I'm an an idiot. As I clearly stated, my code works, except in Chrome. It's clearly some browser-specific quirk and I assumed appropriate Q for SO. Thanks and have yourself a nice day.

Comment: you're writing the value of a certain input element ONLY into this input field!? Try this:  `$('.inputField').blur(function() {
   var input = $.trim($(this).val());
   $('.inputfield').val(input);
});`

Comment: @revaxarts: Tried that, even tried addressing just one field by id, wasn't working. I think your answer pretty much equals my code. Found a workaround, see below. Thanks though.

Comment: Have you tried "change" instead of "blur"?

Comment: @revaxarts: Yes, but .blur works fine. It executes, string gets trimmed, but .val(input) simply doesn't update the input field in Chrome.

Comment: yep seems like jQuery is caching the result. This works btw http://jsfiddle.net/cNerB/

Comment: and this is also strange: http://jsfiddle.net/cNerB/2/ Chrome simple ignores trailing or leading whitespace

Comment: For all who say it's not happening, still happens in Chrome 74 (on MacOS) but only for type="email".

Answer (score 2):

Found an 'ugly' workaround which seems to cooperate in all three browsers:

Added an extra class with nothing inside to the CSS `input.refresh {}`, then added the following code to force a refresh:

```
$(this).addClass('refresh').removeClass('refresh');
```

Comment: Alternatively, see our solution below, changing the input type while trimming.

Answer (score 2):

We solved the issue (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423785) with `focusout` event (which bubbles, `blur` doesn't) and changing the input type while trimming:

```
formElement.addEventListener('focusout', function(event) {
   if (event.target.type === 'email') {
      event.target.type = 'text';
      event.target.value = event.target.value.trim();
      event.target.type = 'email';
   }
});
```

You can still use `blur`, if you use `addEventListener` on `input[type="email"]`, then you can omit the if statement, too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Chrome bug since it only happens when you try to set the value as the trimmed current value. If we found some solution here I'll update my answer sharing that.
Actually if you split the value and update the field twice it will work but I don't think it's an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Can you support your statement with a code example? Is there an outstanding bug report for Chrome regarding this?

Comment: @MarioTacke here you go, a bug ticket from 2014 and still valid: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423785